# Google Tag Manager "element visibility" trigger not triggering GTM tag

Tags: google-tag-manager

I've created an element visibility trigger for the visibility of `#reseller-converted`:

[image]

and a GTM GA4 event tag that is fired by this trigger.

I've previewed/debugged the tag and submitted the form, and the thank you message is created in the DOM through JS fine:

`<h2 id="reseller-converted">Thank you for registering as a reseller</h2>`

However, the GTM preview/debugger shows the tag has not fired:

[image]

Why might this GTM tag not fire?